# usage of infura wss

Tags: web3.py, python, infura, websocket, connections

I am trying to connect to infura via wss protocol, but I get this typerror, can you please help me out with that?

```
from web3 import Web3

# add your blockchain connection information
infura_websocket = 'wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/815e996eff9c4caa8cfe1349781148b6'
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(infura_websocket))

print(w3.isConnected())
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot be fixed in stable 5.x version (at  pypi)

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/2436

Just use 6.x ⚠️ it's BETA

https://pypi.org/project/web3/#history

Comment: The two links points to the same issue, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks @Ismael, fixed.